# Reference and citation

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, citing, biber

I need a Reference style like this: Farhan, A. M. (2017): Effect of rotation on the propagation of waves in hollow poroelastic circular cylinder with magnetic field. Computers, Materials & Continua, vol. 53, no. 2, pp. 129-156. In-text citation should be in the form:[author's last name,year]

My code was

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear,]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{myfile.bib}
```

.
.
.
.

```
\printbibliography
```

[image: PDF]
I got the output as shown in picture: While the authors name appeared in bold. I wanted them to be inside the parentheses like [Yang,2016].

Likewise, my bibliography does not appear at the end of the document. Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: As already said for your question on main meta, please don't post code fragments. Always make a small, but compileable test document. I also asked you if you compile with biber and if you get errors. Please include this in your question.

Comment: Usually this would indicate you haven't run `biber`, see [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/106162). [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/106162) can help with how to run `biber` from within your specific editor.  If you have run `biber` you should get a `.blg` file which should indicate if `biber` ran successfully or encountered any errors.

Comment: Thank you and I think I need to study more about this